# How to merge a object to a array object in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a api response.data

```
[{id: 1, name:"Test 1"},{id: 2, name:"Test 2"}]
```

And my component .vue

```
...
    created() {
       const request = axios.get("***api_url***").then(response => {
          const result = response.data;
          const placeholder = { 'id': 0, 'name': '[Select]' };
          const newObject = result.concat( placeholder.map( item => ({id: item.id, name: item.name}) ) );
          console.log(newObject);
      });
   }
```

I want merge placeholder object to result after api response

Comment: `result.unshift(placeholder)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result is actually a list. You can use the destructuring assignment

```
  const result = [{id: 1, name:"Test 1"},{id: 2, name:"Test 2"}];
  const placeholder = {id:0, name: "[Select]"};

  const newObject = [ placeholder, ...result ];
```

to prepend the placeholder.

To use concat you must wrap the placeholder in a list.

```
[placeholder].concat(result)
```

to achieve the same result in a "more conservative way".

Or you can use the `Object.unshift` as  suggested by @kemicofa ghost.

```
result.unshift(placeholder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Vue is a JavaScript's progressive framework so we can use the same functions of JavaScript here to merge the objects in Vue.

Please use the following feature on your code!

```
Object.assign(target, Obj1, Obj2, ...);
```

Albert